# Proof by Contradiction Minimum Value Proof $f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing

[image: Puby Staker]

Focusing on $x=a$ first.

**My Proof:**

Assume $f'(a) < 0$

$f(x) \le f(x_1)$ for all $x$, this follows from the extreme value theorem.

$$f'(x_1) = 0$$ Because it is a maximum.

$$\exists x_4 \rightarrow f'(x_4) = \frac{f(x_1) - f(a)}{x_1 - a} > 0$$

$$\exists x_5 \in (a, x_4) \rightarrow f'(x_5) = 0$$

Which means, $x_5$ is a minimum.

But I cant get a contradiction.

---

**ONLY HINTS PLEASE**

Comment: Write out the limit for $f'(a)$.  If the limit is negative then there must be an interval of values around $a$ on which it is negative.  Show then that $f(a)-f(x)$ is negative for $x$ in this interval, contradicting the fact that $a$ is a maximum.

Comment: @GregoryGrant, would you mind explaining more?

Comment: The answer given by Marco should get you there.  Assume the derivative at $a$ is negative and use the $\epsilon$ definition of derivative to show there must be an interval of values where $f$ is less than $f(a)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: let $$f'\left(a\right)<0$$ So there are an interval around $a$
  (assume $(a,a+\epsilon)$
  ) such that $f$
  is decreasing in this interval. So if we take $x\in(a,a+\epsilon)$
  ...

Comment: Exactly, then I would take the division. $\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a}$ then the $\lim_{x \to a}$ then $f'(a) \ge 0$. But this is not eh contradiction version. (+1) anywya

Comment: Oh sorry, I haven't see the request. But using this argument you can build a proof by contradiction.

Comment: @Lebes I change the answer.

Comment: What should I do next? I am stuck?

Comment: @lebes If you take $x$
  in that interval, which $f$
  is decreasing, you have $f\left(x\right)<f\left(a\right)$
  and this is the contradiction. Likewise for the other case.

Answer (score 0):

Lebes, within your proof, you may not conclude  $ f' ( x_{1} ) = 0.$ take identity function.

And Marco, within your proof, you may not conclude $f$ is decreasing on $ (a , a+ \epsilon) .$ You can just claim that there is $ x \in (a , a+ \epsilon) $ such that $ f(x)  <  f(a)$, which is enough to obtain desired contradiction.